# Unity API call sometimes return HTTP Error at almost concurrent usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api

Image, general architecture of what I'm doing.
[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hujGW.png)

Unity application is implemented with multiple APIs and being called at different scenario.
Example:
Button 1: Call API 1
Button 2: Call API 2
Button 3: Call API 3

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnY5d.png)
Error as above **sometimes** occur when Button is clicked right after either one of them.

Below is code of what is currently implemented for both front-end(Unity) and back-end(API):

The returned error is reported from application which is front-end(Unity): `UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:`

## **UNITY IDE: API CALL**

```
// The way API is called for Button 1, 2 and 3 are like as below
public IEnumerator APICall()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(URL))
        {
            uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            uwr.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsondata));

            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            switch (uwr.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                    Debug.LogError(uwr.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                    Debug.LogError(uwr.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError(uwr.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                    Debug.Log(uwr.downloadHandler.text);
                    // Some handling
                    Handling();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

## **API**

**DBRepo.cs**

```
 public static class DBRepo
    {
        static DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

        // Interaction with DB: using Entity Framework

        public static void Add()
        {            
        }

        public static void Update()
        {            
        }

        public static void Delete()
        {            
        }

    }
```

**API1Controller.cs**

```
    // Insert data to Table
    public class API2Controller: ApiController
    {
         public IHttpActionResult Get(string id, string status, [FromBody] data)
         {
              Calculation(); // Have pretty complex calculation & funtion before insert data to DB
              DBRepo.Add();
              // return response
         }
    }
```

**API_2Controller.cs**

```
    // Update data
    public class API2Controller: ApiController
    {
         public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
         {
              DBRepo.Update();
              // return response
         }
    }
```

**API_3Controller.cs**

```
    // Delete data
    public class API3Controller: ApiController
    {
         public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
         {
              DBRepo.Delete();
              // return response
         }
    }
```

I don't know where and what fix need to be done.
Is the way API implemented/called incorrect? or Is it network?

Really need advice for this.

Comment: why even have each API call in separate controllers? I would probably rather define routes properly and have them all in one ... where does `jsondata` come from? and how do you pass in the ID?

Comment: Actually I'm taking over this from someone's and I'm quite new in this. Based on his work I think it's because each controller have different function itself, also it's quite a lot.

The `jsondata`  is a record from Table that converted to json.

how do you pass in the ID? --> pass means from API URL?

Comment: I mean if you get a 500 response it means something on the API failed, not in your Unity code => run your Asp.Net in debug and check the console (not the unity one but the IDEs) for errors / exceptions

Comment: Okay will check on that! However, the error only appear in Unity and never appear in Visual Studio at all when running it. Why is that?

Comment: yeah in general [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) can mean a lot of things .. but still it would be something coming from the server itself .. otherwise if it was about the connection etc you would usually rather expect some 4XX error instead

Comment: if it's come from server, is it have something to do with IIS? also the WiFi  bandwidth since it is very restricted